# Nested groups in active directory and permissions?

Tags: directory, groups

I created the image so you could understand what I'm asking:
[image: http://i62.tinypic.com/30bfl1k.png]

These are simple groups created in Active directory. Which permission will be apply on ALI. Full Control or Read Only

Answer (score 0):

NTFS permissions are additive: as ALI is in group1 he will be granted read permissions, and being in group2 also he will be granted write permissions also.